# How to sum all the month wise records using linq to entities?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

My Table like this
Table:

```
id  no.of sales    datetime 
1    14            2013-09-10
2    45            2013-09-09
3    18            2013-09-08
4    14            2013-08-12
5    15            2013-08-14
6    18            2013-07-12
```

Here in above table in 9th month  three rows are there.in 8th month 2 records are there.i need sum of all no.of sales in 9th month and 8th month so on.
Can one please tell me how to acheive this.
MY Query:

```
DateTime frommonth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
DateTime tomonth = DateTime.Now;
var result= from pa in cxt.Products
            where (pa.datevalue >= frommonth && pa.datevalue < tomonth)
                && pa.productname == productname
            orderby pa.datevalue descending
            select new { noofsales=pa.No_of_sales ,datetime=pa.datevalue};
```

By using above query i am getting indidvidual 9th month records .i don't want individual no.of sales i need sum of all 9th month sales,8th month sales and so on.please tell me ...

Comment: have you tried using `.AsEnumerable().Sum(x =>x.No_of_sales)` ?

Comment: @Serv It would move the sum calculation into application memory instead of performing it on DB. Really low efficiency.

Comment: I was considering the same. That's why I posted it as a comment and not an answer. Sometimes you need a quick n dirty solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = from r in cxt.Products
             group r by r.datevalue.Month
             into g
             select new {Month = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(p=>p.No_of_sales)};
```

Comment: I'm afraid it will not work, because `DateTime.Month` cannot be translated into proper SQL statement.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek yes it works. I tested it on EF 5 with .Net Framework 4.5 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: That's really interesting! I'm gonna investigate it myself then :)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Ok. Let me know the result and if you find it helpful please don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Oops! Sorry, you are right. So please up-vote it!

Comment: Where is this answer taking the year into account?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`SqlFunctions.DatePart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487171.aspx) static method, which will be translated into `DATEPART` sql function:

```
var results = from r in ctx.Products
              let year = SqlFunctions.DatePart("yy", r.datevalue)
              let month = SqlFunctions.DatePart("mm", r.datevalue)
              where (r.datevalue >= frommonth && r.datevalue < tomonth)
              group r by new { year, month } into g
              select new {
                  Year = g.Key.year,
                  Month = g.Key.month,
                  NoSales = g.Sum(x => x.No_of_sales)
              };
```

Comment: I need last 4months no.of sales only ?i don't want all months no.of sales.

Comment: Add `where` with date range. Updated my answer.

Comment: I am getting error cannot implicitly convert string to decimal at nosales.for that i am using type conversion but linq to entities doesn't allowin g the conversions.getting exception:LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal ToDecimal (System.String)' method, and this method can not be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @user1237131 Why don't you use the answer I provided?